# I've got strange output from 'componentsSeparatedByString' method of NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, persistence

I want to store the array of NSDictionary to a file. So I write a function to convert from NSArray to NSString. But I got a very strange problem. Here is my code.

```
+ (NSArray *)arrayForString:(NSString*)dataString
{
    NSArray* stringArray = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:ROW_SEPARATOR];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringArray);
    NSMutableArray* dictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (int i = 0; i < [stringArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSString* string = [stringArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
        NSArray* subStrings = [string componentsSeparatedByString:COLUMN_SEPARATOR];
        NSDictionary* dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[subStrings objectAtIndex:0], PHOTO_NAME, [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[[subStrings objectAtIndex:1] unsignedIntValue]], PHOTO_SEQ_NO, nil];
        [dictionaryArray addObject:dic];
    }
    return dictionaryArray;
}
```

Here is the log:

```
2012-05-05 23:57:35.113 SoundRecognizer[147:707] (
    "new Photo/0",
    "new Photo/1"
)
2012-05-05 23:57:35.118 SoundRecognizer[147:707] new Photo/0
2012-05-05 23:57:35.123 SoundRecognizer[147:707] -[__NSCFString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d18c0
```

How do I get a @"-" from this following array?!

```
2012-05-05 23:57:35.113 SoundRecognizer[147:707] (
    "new Photo/0",
    "new Photo/1"
)
```

Comment: What's the string you are passing in, and what are the separator constant values? The @"-" has nothing to do with it, in the code above you assign the same value to `string` before and after the if statement.

Comment: @jrturton. Sorry, that line of code I was adding for debugging. Although I did not mention the dataString and separator, I printed out the stringArray in the log. You see that there is no @"-" in it. I wonder why @"-" is printed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString doesn't have an `unsignedIntValue` method. Use `intValue` instead. But I'm not sure of the point of all this - you can write an array of dictionaries straight to a file anyway (as long as they only contain property list types) using `writeToFile: atomically:`.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes this code runs normally. I think there may be some categories added to NSString so that NSString has a method called "unsignedIntValue" at runtime.(Maybe in NSNumber?)